Foreground Service Notification doesn't appear in Android 14 using .NET 8
As per the title I am trying to implement a service that will have to show an unclosable notification. This notification will have to be compatible with Android 14 and earlier.
However, after repeated attempts and after reading various guides, I still cannot see the notification. Below is the service:
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;

namespace ProjectNecrozma.AndroidTasksHandler
{
    [Service(Name = "com.projectnecrozma.android.tasks.handler.BackgroundService")]
    public class BackgroundService : Service
    {
        private const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private const string CHANNEL_ID = "project_necrozma_channel";

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent? intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
            {
                StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, CreateNotificationService(), Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeSpecialUse);
            }
            else
            {
                StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, CreateNotificationService());
            }

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        private void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Project Necrozma Tasks Handler Channel", NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = "Channel for Project Necrozma Tasks Handler"
                };

                var notificationManager = (NotificationManager?)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                notificationManager?.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }

        private Notification CreateNotificationService()
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle("Project Necrozma Tasks Handler")
                .SetContentText("The service is running.")
                .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                .SetAutoCancel(false);

            return notificationBuilder.Build();
        }

        public override IBinder? OnBind(Intent? intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.projectnecrozma.android.tasks.handler">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <service android:name="com.projectnecrozma.android.tasks.handler.BackgroundService" android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />
</manifest>

MainActivity:
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

namespace ProjectNecrozma.AndroidTasksHandler
{
    [Activity(Label = "TasksHandler", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BackgroundService));

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                StartForegroundService(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                StartService(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm creating this app using .NET 8.

The problem was solved just adding the permission POST_NOTIFICATIONS in the manifest file. Then I have enabled the notification permission in the app settings.
This is the MainActivity with the permission check:
using Android;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;

namespace ProjectNecrozma.AndroidTasksHandler
{
    [Activity(Label = "TasksHandler", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Intent? _serviceIntent;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            _serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(BackgroundService));

            StartService();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                StartForegroundService(_serviceIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission to show notifications is required", ToastLength.Short)!.Show();
                Finish();
                Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
            }
        }

        private void StartService()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu)
            {
                if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != (int)Permission.Granted)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, [Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications], 1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    StartForegroundService(_serviceIntent);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StartForegroundService(_serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}

